# Multiple Column Groups within matrix for invoice grid

Tags: matrix, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I have to present a matrix or tablix on a report which shows the invoices a customer has had in a given month.   It needs to display like this. Where each week is a separate column - managed that - then the row grouping is by weekday e.g. Mon, Tues, that way all the invoices should sort in the same proximity.

When I group by the weekday I do not see all the invoices - there may be multiple invoices on a day. When I group by weekday, invoice number then the grid has four lists for each week but offsets the invoices in the row below each other week

I have honestly been working on this for ages and have tried every grouping an sorting I can think of but cannont get this to work. Tried searches but still cant find anything clear to help.

The Datasource is standard, used both SSAS and DAX separately to get data - that is not a problem as data is correct.        Not sure how to display this layout in this form:

[image: Report layout]

```
Week 1      Week 2      Week3       Week 4  
Inv Amount  Inv Amount  Inv Amount  Inv     Amount
Mon Inv123  50  Inv130  450         Inv912  5
    Inv124  500 Inv133  25              
Tue Inv125  75          Inv245  75      

Wed Inv126  85  Inv156  95  Inv315  15      
                Inv316  50      
Thur            Inv166  10              

Fri Inv127  9               Inv451  15  Inv915  15
```

Comment: Oops forgot to put on this note:   when I group by the weekday I do not see all the invoices - there may be multiple invoices on a day.    When I group by weekday, invoice number then the grid has four lists for each week but offsets the invoices in the row below each other week

Comment: explain how exactly data is looking from your dataset query. put a screenshot of that.

Comment: data in year| Month| Customer Group| Customer Number | Transaction Date| Invoice nu | Amount